# Does anyone know how to get an XP-Pen Star 06 tablet working on Ubuntu/elementaryOS or Linux?

Tags: drivers, tablet

I'm trying to get this (XP-PEN Star 06) tablet to work. I tried DiGiMend on github and installing their drivers etc... did not work. Here is my complete output for the tablet. https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/d5DFQ8V3ZG/

Answer (score 2):

I just ordered this tablet and am waiting for it arrive but looking around for linux drivers I found that Xp Pen have actually released a linux driver Checkout this page https://www.xp-pen.com/download/index/cid/36.html

Answer (score -1):

XP-Pen tablets do not work on Linux full stop. Be a hero and write a driver for it; or else weigh the value of your time spent doing that versus the cost of buying a Wacom tablet that will work.

Comment: um...clearly you have zero clue as to what you're talking about there are plenty of XP-Pen tablets and many others that work on Linux thanks to these folks https://digimend.github.io/ and others. The issue that I'm having is more of a configuration issue than a driver issue. Linux has generic drivers that would work with most tablets be it edev or xinput.